Why isn't the method of assumed states working here?
This is the circuit.
.
Let us use the method of assumed states.
Considering the diode ON

There is no current flow across the 2k resistor.
$$I_D=0$$
So, the diode is not ON. It is OFF (verified).
Considering the diode OFF

$$V_A>V_C$$
$$\text{and}$$
$$V_A-V_C\geq0.7$$
So, the diode is not ON, it is OFF (verified).
Conclusion
I have no idea what to do with these results. The diode appears to be neither ON nor OFF.
My question

Is the diode ON or is it OFF?


This is where one cannot safely assume that Vf of a diode is 0.7V. It will be less, the diode will still be on and SOME current will flow. How much is way more complex question.

If you take a typical silicon diode (like a 1N4148) it will have a forward characteristic like this: -

Image taken from Sparkfun - real diode characteristics.
So, at a forward voltage of 0.7 volts, the current will be approximately 2 to 3 mA at a temperature of 25 °C. In other words, your method is too close to the knuckle for making meaningful on/off conclusions. Diodes are not on/off devices; they have a complex forward conducting characteristic.
